# How to access nested objects in Elastic Search when querying through Java

Tags: java, json, spring, elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search 2.4.5 on a Ubuntu server. I need to access some records via my Java application. First, here how the object appears in Elastic Server.

```
{
"total": 1,
"max_score": 1.0,
"hits": [{
  "_index": "ensembl",
  "_type": "track",
  "_id": "1",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "short_name": "GENCODE M24",
    "long_name": "GENCODE gene set for Mouse Build 24",
    "description": "The gencode gene set is ...",
    "track_type": "gene",
    "genome": {
      "genome_species": "mus_musculus",
      "genome_assembly": "GRCm38",
      "genome_strain": 0
    },
    "release": {
      "release_division": "ensembl",
      "release_version": 89
    },
    "location": {
      "location_type": "mysql",
      "location_object_type": "gene",
      "location_species": "mus_musculus",
      "location_dbtype": "core",
      "location_logic_names": "ensembl"
    }
  }
```

You can see genome, release and location have some sub objects. To access this data object, I created the java model class for this. Here's the code I created.

```
package com.chanaka.book.model;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "ensembl", type = "track")
public class Track {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String short_name;
    private String long_name;
    private String description;
    private String track_type;
    private String genome_species;
    private String genome_assembly;
    private boolean genome_strain;
    private String release_division;
    private int release_version;
    private String location_type;
    private String location_object_type;
    private String location_species;
    private String location_dbtype;
    private String location_logic_names;

    public Track() {

    }
    public Track(int id, String short_name, String long_name, String description, String track_type, String genome_species, String genome_assembly, boolean genome_strain, String release_division, int release_version, String location_type, String location_object_type, String location_species, String location_dbtype, String location_logic_names) {
        this.id = id;
        this.short_name = short_name;
        this.long_name = long_name;
        this.description = description;
        this.track_type = track_type;
        this.genome_species = genome_species;
        this.genome_assembly = genome_assembly;
        this.genome_strain = genome_strain;
        this.release_division = release_division;
        this.release_version = release_version;
        this.location_type = location_type;
        this.location_object_type = location_object_type;
        this.location_species = location_species;
        this.location_dbtype = location_dbtype;
        this.location_logic_names = location_logic_names;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getShort_name() {
        return short_name;
    }
    public void setShort_name(String short_name) {
        this.short_name = short_name;
    }
    public String getLong_name() {
        return long_name;
    }
    public void setLong_name(String long_name) {
        this.long_name = long_name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getTrack_type() {
        return track_type;
    }
    public void setTrack_type(String track_type) {
        this.track_type = track_type;
    }
    public String getGenome_species() {
        return genome_species;
    }
    public void setGenome_species(String genome_species) {
        this.genome_species = genome_species;
    }
    public String getGenome_assembly() {
        return genome_assembly;
    }
    public void setGenome_assembly(String genome_assembly) {
        this.genome_assembly = genome_assembly;
    }
    public boolean isGenome_strain() {
        return genome_strain;
    }
    public void setGenome_strain(boolean genome_strain) {
        this.genome_strain = genome_strain;
    }
    public String getRelease_division() {
        return release_division;
    }
    public void setRelease_division(String release_division) {
        this.release_division = release_division;
    }
    public int getRelease_version() {
        return release_version;
    }
    public void setRelease_version(int release_version) {
        this.release_version = release_version;
    }
    public String getLocation_type() {
        return location_type;
    }
    public void setLocation_type(String location_type) {
        this.location_type = location_type;
    }
    public String getLocation_object_type() {
        return location_object_type;
    }
    public void setLocation_object_type(String location_object_type) {
        this.location_object_type = location_object_type;
    }
    public String getLocation_species() {
        return location_species;
    }
    public void setLocation_species(String location_species) {
        this.location_species = location_species;
    }
    public String getLocation_dbtype() {
        return location_dbtype;
    }
    public void setLocation_dbtype(String location_dbtype) {
        this.location_dbtype = location_dbtype;
    }
    public String getLocation_logic_names() {
        return location_logic_names;
    }
    public void setLocation_logic_names(String location_logic_names) {
        this.location_logic_names = location_logic_names;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", short_name='" + short_name + '\'' +
                ", long_name='" + long_name + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", track_type='" + track_type + '\'' +
                ", genome_species='" + genome_species + '\'' +
                ", genome_assembly='" + genome_assembly + '\'' +
                ", genome_strain=" + genome_strain +
                ", release_division='" + release_division + '\'' +
                ", release_version=" + release_version +
                ", location_type='" + location_type + '\'' +
                ", location_object_type='" + location_object_type + '\'' +
                ", location_species='" + location_species + '\'' +
                ", location_dbtype='" + location_dbtype + '\'' +
                ", location_logic_names='" + location_logic_names + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And also here's the controller code i'm using to access this model and get data from Elastic Server.

```
public class TrackController {

    @Autowired
    private TrackService trackService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private Iterable<Track> findAll() {
        return trackService.findAll();
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, those values in the normal json object appears. But those values in nested json objects, not appearing in the result. Here's the result i'm getting here.

```
{
    "content": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "short_name": "GENCODE M24",
          "long_name": "GENCODE gene set for Mouse Build 24",
          "description": "The gencode gene set is ...",
          "track_type": "gene",
          "genome_species": null,
          "genome_assembly": null,
          "genome_strain": false,
          "release_division": null,
          "release_version": 0,
          "location_type": null,
          "location_object_type": null,
          "location_species": null,
          "location_dbtype": null,
          "location_logic_names": null
        }
    ],
    "last": true,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "sort": null,
    "numberOfElements": 1,
    "first": true,
    "size": 1,
    "number": 0
}
```

You can see those fields are null.ow to get those values to my output? Do I need to change my Track model class?